# If I have a time like 1325982833403 in JavaScript, how do I convert it to a datejs value?

Tags: javascript, datejs

The [JavaScript library I'm using](http://codejoust.github.com/session.js/) represents user login times as long integers:

```
1325982833403
```

How do I convert this to a DateTime ('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt') value that the datejs library would understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Date constructor:

```
var date = new Date(1325982833403*1000);
```

That number is Unix timestamp, google for more information about this, and conversion techniques

Comment: You sure about that? `new Date(1325982833403*1000).toString()` evaluates to `"Wed Sep 21 43988 08:50:03 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"`

Comment: It's 41,976 years in the future?

Answer (score 1):

It's a UNIX timestamp; an extremely useful representation of a moment in time.

```
Unix time, or POSIX time, is a system for describing instants in time, defined as
the number of seconds elapsed since midnight Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) of
Thursday, January 1, 1970 ...
```

(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

In practice, with this particular library ([http://www.datejs.com/](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)), use:

```
<script src="http://datejs.googlecode.com/files/date.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javacript">
    var mydate = Date(1325982833403);
</script>
```